# How can I scale the space taken by a scaled element

Tags: css

All:

I am pretty new to CSS, say if I set scale to one element on the page, it turns out that the element gets scaled but the blank space it took originally still there, I wonder **how can I make that space scaled as well**? If the CSS way can not work, is there any other way to do this( please do not tell me that change the size and move the DIV following left accordingly )?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div id="toscale" style="transform: scale(0.5); transform-origin:top left; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:pink; float:left;">
      
      
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightblue; float:left;">
      
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: You unfortunately cannot. Maybe `transform` isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @MattDiamant Thanks, if not, that is fine, do u know other easy way to do this? I just need a way to implement what I want

Comment: @Kuan Is this for the public web or specific browsers?

Comment: If you want to change the `width` and `height`, the best way to do that is with `width` and `height`.

Comment: @MattDiamant  Thanks, but how do I recursively scale everything inside it?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yah, CSS isn't great at this. `transform` works well because it applies itself after the browser calculates how much space it will take up.

Comment: @MattDiamant Thanks, do you mean I should use transform attribute rather than transform style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If size is known, then it should be easy:

```
transform:scale(0.5); /* /2 */
transform-origin:top left; /* bottom and right need to be minded to swallow the gap */
width:100px; /* /2 = 50px */
margin-right:-50px;
height:100px; /* /2 = 50px */
margin-bottom:-50px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="toscale" style="transform:scale(0.5); transform-origin:top left; width:100px;margin-right:-50px; margin-bottom:-50px;height:100px; background-color:pink; float:left;">


  </div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lightblue; float:left;">

  </div>
  <div>
```

*else a javascript will be needed to retrieve size of element , transform scale value and transform-origin to set the proper negative or positive margins*

Comment: Thanks, this helps!  I guess I have to use it to solve current problem this time.